# Web.config configuration when using separate Project for logging Log4Net

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I have a Visual Studio solution with 2 proyects:

1. Web Application
2. Library project for logging

My Web Application project doesn't have Log4Net reference. The Logging Project is the one that has the reference to the Log4Net dll and it has a Manager Class where I have all the methods for logging.

Now, I want to know what do I have to do in the Web Application WEb.Config file, I saw on the internet that I have to add a Section:

```
 <section name="log4net" 
      type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, 
            log4net"/>
```

But my concern is that my web project doesn't have the Log4Net dll reference. Is there I way I can do that without adding Log4Net dll to my web project?

Comment: Have you tried?  If you are using source control (which you should be of course), you can simply revert if your experiment goes awry.

Comment: Alternatively, a simple scratch solution suffices to answer your question.  I knew from experience that, yes, you can do what you want without adding a reference to `log4net.dll` in your web application project; but I quickly confirmed as much with a scratch solution and posted the resulting answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add the `section` element for log4net without referencing `log4net.dll` in your web application project.

To be sure, I double checked this with a scratch web application project (WebApplication1) and class library (ClassLibrary1) targeting .NET 4.0 in Visual Studio 2013.  ClassLibrary1 referenced `log4net.dll`, but WebApplication1 did not; it just referenced ClassLibrary1 and had a log4net `section` element & related `log4net` element in its `Web.config`: logging to a text file via log4net worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have forgotten to configure log4net. Best practice is to add a configure attribute in your assably.cs:

```
// Configure log4net using the .config file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
// This will cause log4net to look for a configuration file
// called TestApp.exe.config in the application base
// directory (i.e. the directory containing TestApp.exe)
// The config file will be watched for changes.

// Configure log4net using the .log4net file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFileExtension="log4net",Watch=true)]
// This will cause log4net to look for a configuration file
// called TestApp.exe.log4net in the application base
// directory (i.e. the directory containing TestApp.ex
```

You can add the attribute in your log4net dll, there is no need for a reference to log4net in you web project.

Comment: Not necessarily. Of course the OP will need to address that (in the class library) as I did in the double-check I put together. It's really an unrelated point, and there's nothing to indicate that the OP fails to understand as much; but okay.

Comment: Actually there is. It is a very common mistake when starting with log4net. If the logging would have worked, the OP would be able to test it himself and the would have been no question.